Prove that one can find an element of $u_n$ smaller than or equal to $a$.

Let $a$ be an odd natural number and $b$ be a positive integer. We define a sequence of reals $(u_n)$ as follows: $u_0=b$ and, for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$, $u_{n+1}$ is $\frac{u_n}2$ if $u_n$ is even and $a+u_n$ otherwise. Prove that one can find an element of $u_n$ smaller than or equal to $a$.


In the solution given in book, they tackle the case when $u_n$ is even in this manner:
Assuming $u_n> a$, and $u_n$ odd, then $u_{n+1}=u_n /2 < u_n$, and they concluded. But I don't understand how this proves that $u_{n+1} \leq a$?

"they tackle the case when un is even in this manner: Assuming un>a, and un odd"  Huh?  Is $u_n$ even or is it odd?  That entire sentenc makes no sense.  First you are saying they are assuming $u_n$ is even.  Then they say it is odd.  Then they say $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n}2$ mean it has to be even.... so what exactly does the make say?  If it says what you say it says, you should throw it in the garbage as it makes no sense.

All $u_n$ are natural numbers. The natural numbers have the "Well ordering principal" which is nothing more nor less than the set of all $u_n$ must have a least element. (Note: there can be an infinite number of representations of this least value, but there is a least value.)
Let $u_m$ be the least possible $u_n$.  Then $u_{m+1}\ge u_m$.  $\frac {u_m}2 < u_m$ so $u_m$ can't be even.  So $u_{m+1}=a+u_m$.  $a$ is odd and $u_m$ is odd.  So $u_{m+1}$ is even.  So $u_{m+2} = \frac{u_{m+1}}2 = \frac {a+u_m}2$.  If $a < u_m$ then $u_{m+2}< u_m$ which contradicts that $u_m$ was the smallest possible $u_n$.
So there must be a value that is equal or less than $a$.
===== Not using the well ordering principal ====
Every even number can be written as $2^mw$ where $w$ is odd.
If $u_k = 2^nw$ then $u_{k+1}=2^{n-1}w$ and $u_{k+2}=2^{n-2}w$ and so on until we get $u_{k+n} = w$.
And we have $u_k > u_{k+1} > u_{k+2} > ..... > u_{k+m} =w$.
Now if $u_{k+m}=w \le a$ we are done.  There does exist a $u_n \le a$.
But if $u_{k+m}=w$ then $u_{k+m + 1} = w+a$, and even number.  And $u_{k+m+2}=\frac {w+a}2<\frac {w+w}2 = w=u_{k+m}$.
So we have $u_k > u_{k+1} > ....> u_{k+m} > u_{k+m+2}$ And if $u_{k + m + 2} > a$ we can keep going.
Now obviously we can't keep going forever.  Eventually we keep going lower and lower we must hit $0$ eventually.
So this must end some how.  But the only way it can end is if we reach a $u_{h}$ is odd and $u_{h+1} = a+u_h > u_h$ and $u_{h+2} =\frac {a+u_h}2 \ge u_h$.  But the only way that can happen is if $u_h \le a$.
That's the only way the chain can end, and the chain has to end, so that has to eventually happen.
... okay, I like about not using the well ordering principal.  The statement "Now obviously we can't keep going forever.  Eventually we keep going lower and lower we must hit $0$ eventually.  "  Is actually the exact same thing as the well ordering principal.


If $u_n>a$ is true and $u_n$ is even as well as odd, then the strict inequality $u_{n+1} = \frac{u_n}{2} < u_n$ also holds.  [The case when $u_n$ is odd is as noted in the given proof; $u_{n+1}=\frac{u_n+a}{2}<u_n$ as long as the inequality $u_n>a$ is true.]

Likewise, then if the strict inequality $u_{n+1}>a$ is true, then the strict inequality $u_{n+1}>u_{n+2}$ is true [whether $u_{n+1}$ is even or odd]. In turn, if the strict inequality $u_{n+2}>a$ is also true, then so is the strict inequality $u_{n+2}>u_{n+3}$.

So from the reasoning used in 1. and 2. above, if there is no such integer $n' \ge n$ such that $u_{n'} \le a$, then one has an infinite series of positive integers $u_n> u_{n+1}$ $> u_{n+2} > u_{n+3}$ $> \cdots >u_{n+i} > u_{n+i+1} \cdots$ [strict inequality], all of them the $u_{n+i}$s strictly greater than $a$. Can you draw a contradiction from this?


